# i wanna know how to find phonegap icon on my toolbar even i install phonegap plugin on luna eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cordova, plugins

I don't know why I can't find that Evne I installed plugin.

Already I tried to uninstall this plug in n reinstalled but that didn't work.

anybody knows how to handle this ?

Plz help me .

Answer (score 0):

Install cordova using cmd and use that will be better:

install node js, then try :

```
npm install -g cordova
```

then create new project using cmd:

```
    cordova create hello com.example.hello Hello
```

[Please refer this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)